# Javascript start match function on second character

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I'm trying to split a string from the second position in my string which I pass  to the function.

**Current position:**

```
commandHandler(player: PlayerMp, command: string) {
    if(command.startsWith("/", 0)){
        const cmd = command.match(/\S+/g);
        cmd.forEach(element => console.log(element));
    }
}
```

If I pass `"/test this"` to this function then I get the following response: 1) `"/test"` 2) `"this"` while I need the following response: 1) `"test"` 2) `"this"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `slice` to remove the first character then split by whitespace (`/\s+/`)?

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-remove-first-char-string-js/

Comment: Your problem is that `'/'` matches `\S`. Try matching `/\w+/g` instead. `\w` matches word characters, namely, letters, digits and underscores. Depending on your needs you might instead match, for example, `/[a-z]+/g` or `/[a-zA-Z]+/g`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to remove the first character of the string then proceed as before.

```js
const command = "/test this";

if(command.startsWith("/")){
    const cmd = command.slice(1).match(/\S+/g)
    cmd.forEach(element => console.log(element));
}
```